# Javascript Button OnClick not working, method runs normally

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to create a button in Javascript, that when clicked will send an AJAX Request to some PHP Code.

I have already setup 3 buttons that do the same thing and they are all working fine.

The most bizarre thing is that if I call the method directly it runs fine.

The code for the button:

```
<button id="toggle-button">Toggle</button>
```

The Javascript:

```
var toggleButton = document.getElementById('toggle-button');
...
function init()
{
    ...
    toggleButton.onClick = handleToggleClick;
    ...
}

function handleToggleClick(event)
{
    alert("Sending Request");
    var admin_url = "http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
    var data = {
        action : 'toggle',
    }
    $.post(admin_url, data, function(resp) {
        alert(resp);
    });
}
```

I have called the following in the Chrome Developer Tools Console:

```
handleToggleClick(null); // The request is sent
autoScheduleButton.onClick(); // The request is sent
autoScheduleButton.onClick; //It prints out the function
autoScheduleButton; //It displays the HTML of the button.
```

As I mentioned before there are 3 other buttons which do practically the same thing and work fine, so I really can't see why this isn't working.

Hopefully this is just something really obvious i missed.

EDIT:

Originally I made an error while anonymising the code, the code above is now correct in the init method.

Previous code:
    function init()
    {
        ...
        toggleButton.onClick() = handleToggleClick;
        ...
    }

Answer (score 0):

In `init` function you have code like `toggleButton.onClick() = handleToggleClick;`. This means that you assign to the **result** of the `onClick()` function to the `handleToggleClick`.

You need to assign to `onClick` and not call it.
Try this instead `toggleButton.onClick = handleToggleClick;`

```
function init()
{
    ...
    toggleButton.onClick = handleToggleClick;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Very sorry, I made an error while copying the code into stack overflow, the code in the init method was as you said.

Answer (score 0):

The code `toggleButton.onClick() = handleToggleClick;` in the `init` function is  not a right assignment. It actually means You are calling onClick function on toggleButton and then assigning to the result  `handleToggleClick`.

change it ti  `toggleButton.onClick= handleToggleClick` meaning you are listening to a click event on toggleButton and then calling function `handleToggleClick`

Comment: Very sorry, I made an error while copying the code into stack overflow, the code in the init method was as you said.